# Star vs Snowflake schema in data warehousing?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, data-warehouse, star-schema, snowflake-schema

Currently, I've been involved in an **warehouse based intelligent transaction analysis banking system** featuring customer churn behavior, fraud detection & CRM analysis. We've been using `Oracle` as the database & it's completely a data warehousing project with data mining algorithms used for analysis.

We have records of about 1000 customers of a bank. For modeling, whether it is better to use the star schema or snowflake schema or constellation schema? I know the basic difference of star and snowflake schema- normalization of dimension table occurs in snowflake (a.k.a. snowflaking) schema which may be problematic for joining in case of large-sized database.

So, which schema would be better for my case? Answers from experienced programmers involved in data warehousing are highly welcomed!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In brief, my assumption going into a project like this would be that a star schema would be appropriate. I might modify that if it appeared that a dimension was getting too large to efficiently full scan *and* the efficiency of queries against it could be meaningfully improved by snowflaking *unless* that dimension joined to the fact table on a partitioning key (due to difficulties in applying partition pruning on a predicate placed on a snowflaked dimension).

Comment: As a business intelligence architect, what would you say about the most of the practices for selection of schema type in data warehousing? @David Aldridge

Comment: @Zane sorry don't understand -- do you mean things like Inmon vs Kimball?

Comment: Oh, simply to say- which schema you prefer to use in general- star or snowflake while modeling-based on your experience? @David Aldridge