# How to identify Star schema and Snowflake schema?

Tags: database, pentaho, etl, data-warehouse

I have shifted to datawarehouse career recently. I was given a datawarehouse to build on. How do I identify that I should design the datawarehouse on snow flake schema or star schema? what are the factors I should consider for the cases? and usefulness of these schemas in various scenarios.

Comment: Have you tried searching before asking? There are quite a few questions about star vs. snowflake around already on SO, not to mention plenty of information elsewhere on the internet. Also, this question is pretty broad - as answers elsewhere note, the design decision may well depend on some of your requirements and structure, so trying to decide between them without knowing details might be a bad idea. SO might be a better place to ask once you hit a point where you have a specific table you're unsure of how to model.

Comment: Here's a related question where the answer and comments give a key point... start with a star, then you can consider snowflaking if you hit points where it seems like you need it. Those are the points where I'm suggesting it might be an idea to come back and ask for specific advice. Until you hit those points, this is a very broad question with no clear answer. http://stackoverflow.com/q/14318335/3964881

Answer (score 0):

One of the main things you should consider is, Snowflake model uses normalized data and Star model on the other hand uses de-normalized data.

Check this [site](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Snowflake_Schema_vs_Star_Schema) as well which provides a good comparison.